# Excel VBA vlookup using Dates

Tags: vba, loops, excel, vlookup

I am working with **three sheets.** Worksheet **Start Page** has dates from A4 to lastrow. I have a **Fund trend sheet**  with dates from A11 to last row. The vlookup is **searching for Dates** in the  Fund trend sheet based on the list of Dates in the start page sheet. The **search table range** in the Fund trend sheet is **Range(A11:C11) to lastrow**. When the date is found it **offsets (3,0)**, and that value is presented is **sheet Acurred Expenses** Range("C7").  This will **loop till the lastrow** in  sheet start page A4.

=VLOOKUP('Start page'!A4,'Fund Trend'!A11:C21,3,0)

=VLOOKUP('Start page'!A5,'Fund Trend'!A12:C22,3,0)

as code i have not been successful:

```
Sub equity() 

Dim Nav_date As Date 

Dim equity As Integer 

Nav_date = Sheets("Start page").Range("A4") 

equity = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Nav_date,_
 Worksheets("Fund Trend").Range("A11:C12"), 3, False) 

Sheets("Acurred Expenses").Range("C7") = equity 

End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? You might need to set Nav_date = ... to `...("A4").value` (add .value).

Comment: @3578951 run time error 1004 - unable to get the Vlookup  property of the worksheet Function class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this answer can be broken down into three parts:  correctly referencing the properties of a `Range` object, retrieving the last row of data, and using a loop

**Correctly referencing the range's value:**

---

The first thing that I noticed is that you are attempting to assign a `Date` variable as a `Range` object.

This line:

`Nav_date = Sheets("Start page").Range("A4")`

Should be:

`Nav_date = Sheets("Start page").Range("A4").Value`

A `Range` is an object with has properties and methods.  You must explicitly reference **what** it is about the range you want to get.  It's value, it's cell address, etc.

Likewise this incorrect syntax is repeated below.  The line:

`Sheets("Acurred Expenses").Range("C7") = equity`

Should be:

`Sheets("Acurred Expenses").Range("C7").Value = equity`

EDIT: Per the comments [whytheq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1179880/whytheq) raises the point of **default properties**.  Technically the code `Sheets("Acurred Expenses").Range("C7") = equity` is *not* incorrect, and will work, because the default property of the range is `Value`.  I tend to prefer to be more explicit, but that is my personal preference so I always use `Range.Value` so there is not ambiguity.  Either way should work though!

**Retrieving the last row of the worksheet**

---

To find the last used row of the data in the worksheet, we can start at the bottom of the workbook and "look up" until we find the first row (which will correspond to the last row of the data in the worksheet).

This code would be the same as activating the last cell in column A and them pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shit</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

```
Sub LastRow()

    Dim lRow As Long

    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Debug.Print lRow

End Sub
```

To reiterate, this starts at the very bottom row and goes all the way up, returning the row number of where it stops.  This corresponds to the last value entered in column A.  You might need to change A if your data is in a different column.

**The loop**

---

Finally, we can put everything we've learned together.  After you have `lRow` which corresponds to your last row in your set of data we can perform a look for the `VLOOKUP` like so:

```
Sub equity()

    Dim Nav_date As Date
    Dim equity As Integer
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    lRow = Sheets("Start page").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To lRow 'Begin in Row 4 of the "Start page" sheet
        Nav_date = Sheets("Start page").Range("A" & i).Value

        'Tell code to continue even if error occurs
        On Error Resume Next

        equity = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Nav_date, _
         Worksheets("Fund Trend").Range("A11:C12"), 3, False)

        'Check the results of the VLOOKUP, an error number of 0 means no error
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            'Here I use i+3 because the data started in row 7 and I assume
            'it will always be offset by 3 from the "Start Page"
            Sheets("Acurred Expenses").Range("C" & i + 3).Value = equity
        End If

        'Return to normal error handling
        On Error GoTo 0

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for that. I just added Dim i as Integer. I am getting an error at  lRow = Sheets("Startpage").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row.however i changed it to Range("A4"), but no values are populating in the sheet.

Comment: Plus 1 for quality post, nice one!

Comment: What is your error?  Is it `Start page` or `Startpage`.  Omitting a space in the worksheet name would cause an error.

Comment: I am getting a run time error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error.  its on ... Sheets("Start page").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)

Comment: @JoshuaRoss if i change to Sheets("Start page").Range("A4").End(xlUp) . I get not errors but no values are populating .

Comment: nice post. The section `Correctly referencing the range's value:` is a good pointer but most objects in excel have default properties - in the case of the range object the value property is it's default so there is no need to explicitly use this property.

Comment: also this is not good vba: `Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row` ...this is better  `cells(rows.count,1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: True, I guess I had never considered the default properties.  I try to be very explicit with my code and therefore don't typically rely on them, but I added some info about it.   I do agree that your way is better and will update my code accordingly.

Comment: @James, I made a couple code updates, they might correct the issue.

Comment: @JoshuaRoss the changes helped. i am getting a run time error at Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup..message is - "unable to get vlookup property of worksheetfunction class". But if i use the excel recorded code it works with the loop as well.  But excel recorded code can be difficult to maintain in the future.

Comment: That error may occur if your `VLOOKUP` doesn't return anything.  When you use the formula in a cell on an ordinary worksheet it returns a `#N/A` but this will throw an error in VBA.

Comment: I updated the code even further to use error handling to ensure your VLOOKUP is returning a value.

Comment: Thanks very Much most appreciated.